# Fill missing timestamps and values using python

Tags: python, time-series

I have a list of dictionaries such as

```
[{'time': 1594289677756, 'val': 1000.0}, 
{'time': 1594289785475, 'val': 1297.0}, 
{'time': 1594289854490, 'val': 1440.0}, 
{'time': 1594289864474, 'val': 1548.0},
...
... 
{'time': 1594289938481, 'val': 1648.0}]
```

What is required is that these epoch timestamps should not have a gap of more than 1 second. If there is a gap then that needs to be filled in along with a val which could be set to any logical value say value of previous item.
Being new to python I am not sure how this is best accomplished.

So basically output should be like

```
[{'time': 1594289677756, 'val': 1000.0}, 
 {'time': 1594289678856, 'val': 1000.0},
 {'time': 1594289679856, 'val': 1000.0},
  ...
  ...
 {'time': 1594289678856, 'val': 1297.0},
  ...
 ...
... 
{'time': 1594289938481, 'val': 1648.0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your timestamps are in milliseconds, a way to iterate over your data would be the following:

```py
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    prev_item = data[i - 1]
    curr_item = data[i]

    if abs(prev_item["time"] - curr_item["time"]) > 1000:
        # Logic here for gaps greater than 1 second
```

Then, you need to decide what to do when there is a gap greater than 1 second. Keep in mind that if you replace an item with its previous item, you would be accumulating gaps for the following items.